What does 'Why' mean in this case
But maybe we can be friends. Now tell me little flea, what does my blood taste like?”
“Why, your blood tastes of banana milkshake.”
“That’s because I eat lots of bananas,” said the monkey. “Do fleas like the taste of banana milkshake so very much?”
“Well it’s ok, but it gets boring after a while.”
“What if I were to tell you that I know a place that serves honey flavoured milkshake? And another one just across the way that serves hot buttered toast. What would you say about moving over there?”
Now the little flea, realising that his prospects were looking up, replied cheerfully, “Why Brother monkey, that sounds like a great place to live.”

It's the fourth definition here - in this case expressing mild surprise.

Thank you very much

It's an interjection expressing surprise or warning. Like "Oh" or "Zounds" or many others.
